# Using $$ delimiter in SQL script

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL script file with $$ characters that are not recognized. How can I run this script?

```
delimiter $$

CREATE DATABASE `prototipo` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */$$

delimiter $$

USE `prototipo`$$

delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `contract_type` (
  `identifier` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`identifier`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$

delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `customer_id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

Comment: You don't have to keep calling `delimiter`. I think your problem is the first line. AFAIC since the delimiter is still `;` at that point, you'd need to do `DELIMITER $$;` on the first line.

Comment: Also be aware that some SQL tools (e.g. phpmyadmin) won't allow you to specify the delimiter in code (I guess because it has to be set before the query parsing starts). In those cases you need to set the delimiter separately before executing the script.

Comment: What MySQL client are you using to execute this?  `DELIMITER` is a client feature of the command line MySQL client, _not_ a regular MySQL feature or keyword. Other clients offer alternate means of specifying the delimiter.

Comment: i'm using MySql Query Browser; I copied and pasted every single creation of the table and I created the necessary tables. thanks to all